# how to check if device is registered for windows phone push notification

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns

I am using notification hub to register my windows phone device for push notification service.Once if I register my device and again if I register my device for push notification I am getting two notifications means a single device is registering for two time.Can anyone please tell me how to prevent a user to register for more than once.

My code is as:

```cs
    public static async Task SetupPushNotifications()
    {  
      await RegisterWithNotificationHub();
    }

    private static HttpNotificationChannel CreateHttpNotificationChannel(string channelName)
    {
        var httpChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);
        #endregion   
        return httpChannel;
    }

    private static async Task RegisterWithNotificationHub()
        {
            try
            {
                // requesting a channel from MPNS
                App.NotificationChannel = CreateHttpNotificationChannel("");

                App.ClientHub = new NotificationHub(
                    "",""
                    );
                var storedTagsForUser = await GetRegistrationsTagsFromBackEnd();

                await RegisterTemplateNotificationWithNotificationHub(storedTagsForUser);

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exc);
            }
        }

     private static async Task RegisterTemplateNotificationWithNotificationHub(IEnumerable<string> tags)
        {
            var toastMessageTemplate =
                    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                        "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                            "<wp:Toast>" +
                                "<wp:Text1>$(oppTitleValue)</wp:Text1>" +
                                "<wp:Text2>$(myToastMessage)</wp:Text2>" +
                                "<wp:Param>$(pageToOpen)</wp:Param>" +
                            "</wp:Toast>" +
                        "</wp:Notification>";

            try
            {
                await App.ClientHub.RegisterTemplateAsync(
                        App.NotificationChannel.ChannelUri.AbsoluteUri,
                        xmlTemplate: toastMessageTemplate,
                        templateName: TemplateRegistrationName,
                        tags: tags);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error registering template notification with notification hubs: " + exc);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the channel already exists by calling `HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName)`. It will return null if it doesn't.

So you would only want to create a channel if it doesnt't already exist. For example

```cs
private void RegisterPushChannel()
{
    HttpNotificationChannel currentChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("MyPushChannel");

    if (currentChannel == null)
    {
        currentChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyPushChannel");
        currentChannel.Open();
        currentChannel.BindToShellTile();
        currentChannel.BindToShellToast();
    }
}
```